# Prometheus: How to test retentionSize or retentionTime to avoid no space left and other prometheus errors

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-alertmanager, prometheus-operator

**Problem statement:**
We recently have had different errors in prometheus:

1. msg="error tailing WAL" err="open /prometheus/wal/00001428: no such file or directory"
2. `level=error ts=2022-04-05T23:49:43.453Z caller=main.go:865 err="opening storage failed: open /prometheus/wal/00002430: no space left on device" (END)`
3. sometime metrics won't show up on our observability UI.

**What we did?**
So we increased the storage but the no space left on device error came back.Though
***--storage.tsdb.retention.time*** is also there in the configuration.

After going through various posts and [prometheus docs](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/storage/#operational-aspects) found that there is a need to specify  ***--storage.tsdb.retention.size***. So now I have following in my configuration:

```
  storage:
    size: 60Gi
    storageClassName: gp2
  retention: 15d
  retentionSize: 40GB
```

I want to understand how to test retentionSize (*--storage.tsdb.retention.size*) and retention period (*--storage.tsdb.retention.time*)

From prometheus docs, storage will be dropped once it reaches the retention.size. If both time and size retention policies are specified, whichever triggers first will be used.

**What I want to do?**

1. I want to replicate the scenario when prometheus drops the storage once it reaches retention time or retention size. I have a demo cluster running where I even specified minimum retention period and retention size but I don't see the storage getting dropped
2. What kind of alert should be expected when prometheus storage drops.

Note: I am new to Prometheus so I am sorry if these questions are asked previously but I couldn't find complete answer. Thanks !!